# How to remove all Couchdb versions in Ubuntu 10.04 (server)? ( after multiple installs )

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb

I have done multiple installs of CouchDB using 
sudo aptitude install couchdb
sudo ap-get install couchdb

and more recently based on the instructions found at L http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Ubuntu

May I know how do I uninstall or remove all the above installations?

Best Regards.
+++++++++++++++++++UPDATE++++++++++++++++++++++++

I've tried running the following commands:

```
apt-get remove couchdb
apt-get purge couchdb
```

but received the following errors:

```
(Reading database ... 39814 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing couchdb ...
invoke-rc.d: initscript couchdb, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing couchdb (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
invoke-rc.d: initscript couchdb, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 couchdb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

May I know how do i fix this?

ON issuing the command : dpkg -l | grep couchdb
I received the following response:

```
rF  couchdb                          0.10.0-1ubuntu2                            RESTful document oriented database, system D
iF  couchdb-bin                      0.10.0-1ubuntu2                            RESTful document oriented database, programs
```

How do i uninstall CouchDB ? I think there's some file corruption?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everything you install with apt-get aptitude or dpkg can be uninstalled using the same tool.

As The NinjaSysadmin pointed before use `apt-get remove couchdb` to uninstall

You can also use `apt-get purge couchdb` to remove config and other files.

To see if you have couchdb installed search for it using dpkg -l | grep couchdb

Comment: Excellent tip about 'purge'.

Answer (score 4):

You should stop couchdb before remove it :
$ sudo /etc/init.d/couchdb stop
Then 
$ sudo apt-get remove couchdb
$ sudo apt-get purge couchdb

Comment: Thanks. Worked great, unlike the top rated reply which suggests to try something the question said he already tried...

Answer (score 4):

I was searching on how to completely uninstall couchdb 0.1 provided with Ubuntu in order to develop on Latest Couchbase releases.

You need to **apt-get remove couchdb-bin**

Found the answer in this mail archive:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/201008.mbox/%3C20100807021919.GH6131@orbital%3E

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> sudo apt-get remove couchdb

Answer (score 0):

Anyone have a different answer?  From what I gather, the couchdb 0.1 instance is used by the O/S itself.  I am also trying to remove this, but can't.  Is there a way to upgrade it to 1.0.1 at least?

FYI I've already tried to sudo apt-get remove as well as upgrade.

*UPDATE*

I managed to run 1.0.1 side-by side with the internal 0.10 version.  It was long and complex and I didn't really know what I was doing, but the basic steps are as follows:

- sudo apt-get remove couchdb
- Download the .bin to some folder and extract/install (I followed [this article](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Ubuntu) - installing from source)
- Chmod and chown as in that article
- You also need to do the same to the .delete folder in installFolder/var/lib/couchdb
- Change the port number in the local.ini file to something else
- While you're in there, add a couchdb user
- assign that new user to the couchdb group

Restart couchdb and you should now have 1.0.1 running on a new port as 0.10

Comment: yeah I've tried the usual commands  sudo apt-get remove, upgrade,aptitude remove and so on but none of them worked. i've enve tried installing couchone from http://www.couchone.com/get (ubuntu version), and ran sudo service couchdb stop. but no avail. it still runs version 0.10.0. how do we fix this?

Comment: Is the number just reported incorrectly? I removed my `1.0.1` version but I can't seem to find (or stop) the `0.10.0` version.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use a different port.  Have you guys tried this?