# How do I completely remove all references to couchdb from Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: bash, uninstall, couchdb, ubuntu-11.10

I have [removed and purged couchdb](https://serverfault.com/questions/221459/how-to-remove-all-couchdb-versions-in-ubuntu-10-04-server-after-multiple-in) from Ubuntu, but if I type "couchdb" in the shell at any point, the system still tries to start it up before crashing. I checked **/usr/bin**, and I still have references to couchdb, even after I purged:

```
$ /usr/bin: ls couch*
couchdb  couchdb-dump  couchdb-load  couchdb-replicate  couchjs  couchpy
```

1. What's the safest way to remove these references? Can I simply delete them, or will other artifacts be left behind?
2. I also checked `.bash_profile, .bashrc, .profile, /etc/profile` - are there other spots I should look for artifacts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the package name for a given file, use:

```
dpkg --search /usr/bin/couchdb
```

on my system this returns `couchdb-bin`, then you should do:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove couchdb-bin
```

Repeat as many times as needed.

Answer (score 0):

check the deb package in archive

eg.

/var/cache/apt/archives/couchdb_1.0.1-0ubuntu15_all.deb

you can open this with archive manager and check what all changes were made to system when this package was installed. (DEBIAN folder has this information) Other folders corresponf to your root ("/") file system