# Why does CouchDB persist on my machine despite having removed it? And how do I remove it fully (Ubuntu 11.10)?

Tags: couchdb

I want to reinstall CouchDB on my machine, but I need to remove it fully first.  I removed both couchdb and couchdb-bin packages using

```
sudo apt-get remove couchdb
sudo apt-get purge couchdb
```

However, when i perform

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984
```

I still get

```
{"couchdb":"Welcome","version":"1.0.1"}
```

...and the configurations of the old installation is still intact (when I query the /_config API), which I don't want.

What am I doing wrong?

Yes, the question is similar to [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/348044/how-do-i-completely-remove-all-references-to-couchdb-from-ubuntu-11-10), but only in that it is about fully removing this package.  My situation is different, and I've tried all the suggestions there but they haven't worked for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simple need to kill the process.
Use this :

```
sudo killall -9 couchdb
sudo killall -9 beam
```

Simply restarting will also do the trick, but just in case you are not at a liberty to restart you have the above commands at hand.

Answer (score 3):

You removed the packages but the process is still running.
You need to stop the process.
The init script is now probably removed too, so just kill the couchDB process.